# Broken urls with http site and https wp-admin

Tags: images, urls, https, http

I am currently using a wordpress installation in which all the website is intended to be shown in http while the https part is protected by a self signed certificate, distributed manually to the admins. The problem I have is that the images uploaded are all uploaded with the "https" prefix, I imagine because the link is generated somehow using the full path of the admin interface. 
Do you know how I can fix this behaviour to use the protocol http for every image uploaded? I don't really need https for this and the site name and URL is in http.

Thanks in advance.

Some specs:

- wordpress version: 4.2.1
- plugins installed: Category Posts Widget, Jetpack, Post Types Order, Relative Image URLs, WordPress SEO, WP Statistics.

Comment: Do you have http or https under "Settings" -> URL? If you have https all urls will be saved with https.

Comment: I got all http, that's the strange thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem: the SEO plugin by Yoast is breaking the images as described, doing (probably) a URL rewrite at the time the media is upload. I resolved temporarily bye disabling the plugin. I will then find a better solution analyzing why the plugin is behaving in such a way and update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to make the whole site https. Either add https to the `settings -> wordpress address` & `settings -> site address` or remove https if it appears in either of those inputs.

**For securing admin login panel only:**

1. [easy method but doesn't show secure icon](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/using-ssl-for-login-only).
2. [right result but more steps to consider method](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/securing-admin-login-only).

Comment: I just wanted to skip the CA as I have only one admin and few users.

Comment: I'm still unsure why you want to use https to the admins only. Are you just wanting https for the login pages or the entire wp-admin panel?

Comment: I just need it for the login, but currently the whole wp-admin panel is in https.

Comment: @Raffo have updated my answer with links to discussions and posted solutions for securing the admin login panel only.